# How can I use cURL's '@' syntax with a remote URL?

Tags: php, file, curl

I know this to be true:

> ... you can post a file that is already on the filesystem by prefixing the filepath with "@".

However, I'm trying to POST a file with cURL that's not local. It's stored on some other URL. Let's just say this photo is [Google's logo](https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png) (it isn't). The URL of that is `https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png`. So I would think that you would do something like this:

```
$file = file("https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png");
// some more stuff
// define POST data
$post_data = array('somekey' => 'somevalue', 
                    'image' => '@' . $file);
```

However, this doesn't seem to work for whatever reason. Also, I tried using `'image' => '@' . file_get_contents($url)`. Again, that didn't work.

It looks like a way to get around this is to use a temporary file. Is this the only solution to this problem? In either case, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: You mean `$file = file_get_contents('...');` instead?

Comment: @AmalMurali Do I have to use that for a non-local file?

Comment: have you tried just doing `$file = "https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png";`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You **can not** use any `http` url for the file path at curl. You have to use local file. So first download the file into a temporary directory.

```
file_put_contents("/var/tmp/xyz/output.jpg", file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"));
```

Then use this temporary file into your curl:

```
'image' => '@/var/tmp/xyz/output.jpg'
```

Comment: Yep, you are correct. Thanks! One last question: will the file automatically delete itself or will I need to manually delete it? Or will it automatically overwrite itself?

Comment: It will not delete automatically. It will automatically overwrite when you call it next time. But at the end of the day when program ends, you can delete it if you want.