# PHP: CurlFile upload with remote URL

Tags: php, rest, curl, file-upload

From past few days I have been searching on how to upload file in PHP >=5.5 with Curl. Finally I found the new [CurlFile](http://php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php) method but cant get it work with remote URLs. Here is the code i am using:

```
        $access_token = 'MY_API_ACCESS_TOKEN';
        $fields = array(
            "name" => $name,
            "parent" => array(
                "id" => $folder_id
            )
        );
        $another = array(
            'attributes' => json_encode($fields),
            'file' => new CurlFile($remoteUrl)
        );
        $header = array (
            "Authorization: Bearer $access_token",
            "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"
        );
        $options = array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $UPLOAD_URL,
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $another,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
        );
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```

When replacing the `$remoteUrl` with local file path everything works fine.

**Q] Is the remote upload possible with CurlFile? If yes what am I doing wrong?**

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you found the solution yet?

Comment: @WouterdenOuden: Its not possible to upload file with curl for remote URL.

**Source here**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736756/how-can-i-use-curls-syntax-with-a-remote-url

Comment: After much trial and error I came to the same conclusion.

Comment: @WouterdenOuden: Same here. Actually my PHP app was deployed on [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com) which does not has persistent file storage so finding a way to directly upload to storage drive. But I guess I might have to find another option.

Comment: I just realized that i'm able to get the files locally, because there on the same server. But I will remember this :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I found the answer: [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736756/how-can-i-use-curls-syntax-with-a-remote-url)

**Its not possible to upload a remote file with curl**. One has to download the file locally first and then use CurlFile to upload.