# How to add product images with Prestashop API

Tags: php, api, web-services, curl, prestashop

I'm trying to add/upload product images via Prestashop API, but I'm getting server error 500.
What can be wrong with the code? Or maybe there's something wrong with the server configuration?

PHP script:

```php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://MY_AUTH_KEY@my-shop.com//api/images/products/24/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'MY_AUTH_KEY:');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('image' =>'@http://my-shop.com/img/my-shop-logo-1584646645.jpg;type=image/jpg'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$curlinfo = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r($curlinfo);
```

This results in [http_code] => 500. There's no error or anything. I have access to the hosting provider's server error log, but there's nothing in there...

The script is based on the Prestashop docs: https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/development/webservice/tutorials/change_product_image/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer - You cannot upload remote files with cURL. It can only send local files. So you need to download the file, save it locally and then use cURL with local path.

Source:
[How can I use cURL's '@' syntax with a remote URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736756/how-can-i-use-curls-syntax-with-a-remote-url)

Answer (score 1):

Try with :

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

$image_path = 'http://my-shop.com/img/my-shop-logo-1584646645.jpg';
$image_mime = 'image/jpg';

$args['image'] = new CurlFile($image_path, $image_mime);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://my-shop.com/api/images/products/24/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'MY_AUTH_KEY:');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$curlinfo = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r($curlinfo);
```

Comment: I've already tried that before, but I don't get any http status here at all... I'm using PHP Version 7.2.29. CURL's output in that case is: 
`Array
(
    [url] => http://my-shop.com/api/images/products/24/
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 0
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0`

Comment: Try to activate Prestashop errors, and try again, because error 500 will suddenly give a more precise error

Comment: Do you mean debug mode? I've tried that too, but it doesn't seem to affect API. Can't figure out what's wrong

Comment: I've tried to point the script elsewhere and it seems to be an issue with cURL/CurlFile itself, as there's the same outcome -> no response code. I need to check the server configuration. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: On server, check : allow_url_fopen = on